# How to install Intel 82852/855GM driver on Ubuntu 10.10 "Maverick meerkat"?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, intel-centrino

When I installed Arch Linux on my Toshiba L10 Intel Centrino laptop, it detected my video card and monitors correctly "out-of-the box". Now that I've installed Ubuntu 10.10 "Maverick Meerkat", it has not.

How can I configure Ubuntu to use the correct Intel drivers with my Intel 82852/855GM graphics card?

Comment: Created the tag, but unfortunately I can't help with the question.  I have a similar problem, but I'm waiting for development for my chip set to be released.  Hope someone here can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to download and install the Intel drivers:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:glasen/intel-driver
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Before adding the Device section to the file: `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`

After restarting X (say: reboot), you should be able to change preset resolutions via Systems > Preferences > Monitors.

You can verify the available resolutions with:

```
$ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1360 x 768, maximum 2048 x 2048
VGA1 connected 1360x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1360x768       59.8* 
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   848x480        60.0  
   640x480        59.9     59.9
```

If you require a seemingly exotic resolution, e.g. 1920x1080 (60Hz), you need to add a extra modeline to X. The modeline parameters can be calculated with the cvt tool:

```
$ cvt 1920 1080 60
# 1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

Add this new modeline to your X configuration using xrandr:

```
$ xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

You can check this using xrandr -q again:

```
$ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1360 x 768, maximum 2048 x 2048
VGA1 connected 1360x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1360x768       59.8* 
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   848x480        60.0  
   640x480        59.9     59.9  
   1920x1080_60.00   60.0
```

Finally, add the exotic modeline (VGA1 is the actual output device, as reported by xrandr -q):

```
$ xrandr --addmode VGA1 1920x1080_60.00
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same card in my laptop. To the get the card working I changed the driver in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` to intel:

```
Section "Device"
 Identifier "Configured Video Device"
 Driver  "intel"
EndSection
```

and changed:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.modeset=1"
```

in `/etc/default/grub`

Run `update-grub` after making these changes and reboot.